# Different predictive models giving identical results? Python 2.x to 3.x issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm working on an online course and used the provided code to create two different predictive models. I played around with them a bit to see if I can get different results, which went fine.

My concern is why they are giving me identical accuracy and cross validation scores.

Logit Regression:
[image: Logit Regression]

Decision Tree:
[image: Decision Tree]
I've provided a snippet of code below, as well as the function for classification that I took from python 2.x code. Currently, I am working with python 3.x and 0.17.1 of scikit-learn.

```
# import models from scikit-learn 
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold # for K-fold cross validation
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, export_graphviz
from sklearn import metrics

# generic fxn for making classification model and processing accessing performance
def classification_model(model, data, predictors, outcome):
    model.fit(data[predictors], data[outcome]) # fit model
    predictions = model.predict(data[predictors]) # make predictions on training set

    # print accuracy
    accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(predictions, data[outcome])
    print("Accuracy: %s" % "{0:.3%}".format(accuracy))

    # k-fold cross validatiom, 5 folds
    kf = KFold(data.shape[0], n_folds = 5)
    error = []
    for train, test in kf:
        train_predictors = (data[predictors].iloc[train,:]) # filter training data
        train_target = data[outcome].iloc[train]
        model.fit(train_predictors, train_target)

        # record error from each run
        error.append(model.score(data[predictors].iloc[test,:], data[outcome].iloc[test]))

        print("Cross-Validation Score: %s" % "{0:.3%}".format(np.mean(error)))

        # fit model (again) so it can be referred to outside fxn
        model.fit(data[predictors], data[outcome])
```

Am I using outdated parameter names? Or is there something wrong with the classifier function?

I currently am not getting any errors from the code that I'm running but getting the exact same accuracy and cross validation scores is concerning.

Comment: What is the type of `data`? In `data[predictors]` you are use a _list_ as an indexer (in your examples, `predictors` is always a list), but in `data[outcome]` you have a _string_ as an indexer. This strikes me as odd, to say the least.

Comment: Probably the code in `classification_model()` is incorrect: it's hard-coded. Other possibility: look to columns 'Gender', 'Married', 'Education', they may be constant.

Comment: @AlexVanLiew `data` is a `pandas.DataFrame`. You can slice using `strings` or a `list` of `strings` that usually represent the names of your columns

Comment: Why don't you use `data[outcome].iloc[test, :]` as you've done before everytime you slice. This might not be the answer to your issue because `iloc[]` is supposed to accept list of `int`

Comment: This isn't code I've written, I've simply edited it for the python 3.x. I'm am trying to understand how `classification_model` is affecting the outcome. 

@sergzach, what do you mean by the columns may be constant?